# How to pass custom option to twig template of custom Symfony FormType?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

How can I pass custom options **directly** to the Twig template of a custom `Symfony 3.4` FormType?

---

**Context:**

I have created a custom `FormType` which also uses a custom Twig template to render its form widget. The *build-in options* (e.g. translation_domain, `lable_attr`, etc.) are directly accessible in the template. How can I achieve the same for my custom options?

```
// MyCustomType.php
class MyCustomType extends AbstractType {
    public function getBlockPrefix() {
        return 'my_custom_field';
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'custom_option' => 'customOptionValue',
            'translation_domain' => 'customTranslationDomain',
        ]);
        
        $resolver->setAllowedTypes('custom_option', ['string']);
    }
}

// form_widgets.html.twig
{% block my_custom_field_widget %}
     {{ dump() }}
     {{ translation_domain }}
     {#{ custom_option }#}
{% endblock %}
```

Of course this form widget is not very useful, it only dumps the available variables and the content of `translation_domain` which is directly accessible. Adding `{{ custom_option }}` will lead to an error, since this option/variable is not available. Neither directly nor via `form.vars.custom_option`.

Only when setting the option as form var, it can be accessed in the template:

```
// MyCustomType.php
class MyCustomType extends AbstractType {
    ...

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options) { 
        $view->vars['custom_option'] = $options['custom_option'];
    }
}

// form_widgets.html.twig
{% block my_custom_field_widget %}
     // fails
     {{ custom_option }}

     // works
     {{ form.vars.custom_option }}
{% endblock %}
```

So, all *built-in options* are available in `form_vars` but can also be accessed directly (e.g. as `form.vars.translation_domain' AND as` translation_domain`).

**How do I achieve the same for my custom options?**

Of course accessing the option via `form.vars...` is no problem. However, I wonder if this is the correct solution since the build-in types are accessible directly. Are these just shortcuts (how are they added?) to the `form.vars...` or is this some other configuration?

Comment: Side note: Symfony 3.5? 3.4 was the last one under Sf3.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @El_Vanja, `Symfony 3.4` is correct of course :-)

Comment: You should have a look to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29410622/5224479) :)

Comment: @Mcsky The linked post describes exactly what I wrote: Using `$resolver->setDefaults(...)` and additional adding the option to `$view->vars[...]` works. However, this makes the option only available via `form.vars...` while all build in options are directly accessible. Thus the question is, if this is the only / correct way to go for custom options, or if there is another / better / correct solution?